# Python 3 - Scipy and KDEpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, gaussian

I am using python-3.x and I want to Evaluate the estimated pdf on a provided set of points using the KDEpy but I couldn't get it right,

I used the **scipy.stats.gaussian_kde** and it is fine and work very well when I apply the pdf Method as I am interested in the **Evaluate the estimated pdf on a provided set of points**.

so the question is how to get the same result from the scipy.stats.kde if I used the KDEpy FFTKDE

here a small example that describes what I am looking for:

```
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
data = np.array([[-1.84134663, -1.42036525, -1.38819347],
              [-2.58165693, -2.49423057, -1.57609454],
              [-0.78776371, -0.79168188,  0.21967791],
              [-1.0165618 , -1.78509185, -0.68373997],
              [-1.21764947, -0.43215885, -0.34393573]]) 


my_pdf = gaussian_kde(data.T, bw_method = None  )    
my_pdf1.pdf(data.T)
print (my_pdf1.pdf(data.T)) # here we will Evaluate the estimated pdf on a provided set of points
```

the result is:

```
[0.24234078 0.22071922 0.23802877 0.22474656 0.25402297]
```

how to get the same result by using the **KDEpy FFTKDE**

```
from KDEpy import FFTKDE
my_pdf2 = FFTKDE(kernel="gaussian").fit(data.T).evaluate()
```

but I don't know how to do the Evaluate the estimated pdf on a provided set of points similar to the **scipy.stats.kde** with pdf method.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an equidistant grid using e.g. `numpy.linspace` and pass it to `.evaluate()`:

```
from KDEpy import FFTKDE
import numpy as np
x_grid = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=2**10)
my_pdf = FFTKDE(kernel="gaussian").fit(data.T).evaluate(x_grid)
```

Comment: thanks but I get this error: `ValueError: Shape of data and grid points must be the same.` I am not sure why?